# Strange "Val cannot be reassigned" error when setting a property in Kotlin of a Java object

Tags: kotlin

The strange thing is that my Kotlin code compiled fine before, when it looked like this in the java class `Allocator`:

```
public void setAllocMethod(@NotNull AllocMethod allocMethod) {
    this.allocMethod = allocMethod;
}
```

but when I changed the java class' setter to this:

```
public void setAllocMethod(@Nullable AllocMethod allocMethod) {
    this.allocMethod= allocMethod;
}
```

then when I compile the project, I get this Kotlin error in the kt file that calls the java object:

> Val Cannot be Reassigned

`allocator.allocMethod = DefaultAllocMethod() // kotlin code`

also here is the java getter:

```
public @NotNull AllocMethod getAllocMethod() {
        if (allocMethod == null) allocMethod = DefaultAllocMethod.newDefault();
        return allocMethod;
}
```

`DefaultAllocMethod` is a java subclass of `AllocMethod`

`allocator` is of type `Allocator`, which is a java class that has the getter and setter described above.

Can anyone explain what is happening? thanks

Comment: Could you also expand in the question how the java getter method looks like?

Comment: ok, done... do you think the problem is that the getter returns `@NotNull` but the setter's parameter is `@Nullable` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your setters's type `@Nullable AllocMethod`, which is Kotlin's `AllocMethod?`, does not match the getters type `@NotNull AllocMethod`, which is Kotlin's `AllocMethod`

What the error message means is that since the types do not match, only the getter is considered as a property. So from the Kotlin's point of view instead of a `var allocMethod` you have `val allocMethod` and `fun setAllocMethod(...)`

Comment: yes, that is how I wanted the java class to behave. If the setter was passed a null then `DefaultAllocMethod` would be used (returned from the getter). oh well, I guess this is fine for java but not compatible with Kotlin. I still don't really understand the error message, what this has to do with *val being reasssigned`. Maybe in this day and age my method of programming is rather stupid (using this type of lazy initialization), I think I'll just create a `DefaultAllocMethod` to initialize the `allocMethod` property, that way everything can be `@NotNull``

Comment: That will probably be better. Anyways, please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Remember that an `AllocMethod?` is an `Any?` and that an `AllocMethod` is an `Any`. That helps to understand why these getters and setters don't match up.